# How to make the map bounds responsive in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I'm building a responsive application with a leaflet map container. The map container resizes based on user action (left and right panels over the map collapse). **I want the max bounds of the map to re-adjust when the map container resizes.**

How do I do this?

Comment: To which bounds shall the map be changed on a resize event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to listen to the user event and call invalidateSize() on the map. The map will resize to the max bounds of the map's container. 
something like this :

```
map.leafletElement.invalidateSize()
```

you can read more about it on Leaflet's github issues:
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/941

Comment: This works. Thank you! Is it possible to do this without panning the map though?

Comment: I tried MapService.map.invalidateSize({pan: false});

Comment: In 2019 this command is failing, _maybe_ the `leafletElement` has been renamed.  I got:  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalidateSize' of undefined`